Django DRF: Not receiving refresh token cookie in TokenRefreshView
I'm working on a Django REST Framework project with JWT authentication. I'm trying to implement a token refresh mechanism using HTTP-only cookies, but I'm having trouble receiving the refresh token cookie in my TokenRefreshView.The token set in the SignIn view
Here's my SignIn view where I set the cookie:
class SignIn(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def post(self, request):
        # ... authentication logic ...
        if user.check_password(password) and user.is_active:
            token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            context = {
                "detail": "Sign in successful",
                "user": user_data,
                "token": str(token.access_token),
            }
            response = Response(context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            response.set_cookie(
                "refresh_token",
                str(token),
                httponly=True,
                max_age=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFE_TIME"].total_seconds(),
            )
            return response

Here is my token refresh view
class TokenRefreshView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def post(self, request):
        refresh_token = request.COOKIES.get("refresh_token")
        print(request.COOKIES)  # This prints an empty dict
        print("refresh", refresh_token)  # This prints "refresh None"
        if not refresh_token:
            return Response(
                {"error": "Refresh token not found"},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            )
        # ... rest of the view ...

Axios configuration
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


Is the purpose of RefreshTokenVew to reissue and return access_token through the delivered refresh_token? And the logic to reissue access_token provided by simple-jwt is that the client sends the data in the request body. But when I look at your RefreshTokenView, You try to extract refresh_token from the header. Is this intended?

Yes, I want the RefreshTokenView to reissue the access_token using the extracted refresh_token in the request header cookie pass it to simple-jwt for a new access_token and return the new access_token
